# How to call an API using raw input using Guzzle

Tags: api, guzzle

I have an API which is working well with Postman but upon trying to call it in code, I get errors. See below

**In Postman**
[image: Result in Postman]

Below is how I am calling the API in code:

**In Code**

```
 public function pay_bill(Request $request){

        $client = new Client(); //GuzzleHttp\Client

        $username = 'xxxx';
        $password = 'xxx@2020*';

        $credentials = base64_encode("$username:$password");

        $transaction_id = intval($request->input('transaction_id'));
        $amount = (int)$request->input('amount');
        $bill_number = (int)$request->input('bill_number');
        $return_url = $request->input('return_url');
      
        $response = $client->post('https://gatewaytest.e.com:5000/gateway/initialize', [
             'headers' => [
                'Accept' => 'application/json',
                'Authorization' => 'Basic ' .  $credentials,
                'X-API-KEY' =>  '7c4a8d09ca3762af61e59520943dc26494f8941b',
            ],
            'form_params' => [
                'transaction_id' => $transaction_id,
                'total_amount' => $amount,
                'bills' => ["bill_ref" => $bill_number, "amount" => $amount],
                'return_url'=>  $return_url
            ],
            'verify' => true
        ]);

        $transaction_data = $response->getBody();
        return $transaction_data;
   }
```

What am I doing wrong? How do I send body as raw like is done in postman? I imagine the problem could be due to using form_params

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution as shown below:

```
'bills' => [["bill_ref" => $bill_number, "amount" => $amount]]
```